# Magento 2 installation, redirect 404 issue

Tags: php, git, magento, magento2

I am facing a redirect 404 issue while installing Magento 2.
here are the steps i followed

```
1 - git clone this repo
2 - composer install in the root of the project
3 - composer install in the setup folder
4 - Enabled php_intl extension
5 - Created a virtual host magento2dev.com
```

Now when in browser, i run http://magento2dev.com This redirects me to 404 http://magento2dev.com/setup/en_US/index

Nothing is displayed in log ...

Using version alpha95, and now tried alpha96 But same problem.

any suggestions ???

Answer (score 1):

Please install composer under `root/home` directory and then copy the `composer.phar` to `user/local/bin` directory so that it can be accessible from everywhere (assuming you have Ubuntu or Linux).

Answer (score 0):

Right now, due to the unstable web interface of the installer, it is recommended to use CLI instead.

[Here](https://github.com/magento/magento2#sample-localhost-installation) is a described sample installation.

Answer (score 0):

Installing Magento 2 has always been an issue for me too. But it seems like using Docker is one of the best solution in my case. I ran a container which has a pre-built Magento 2 with all its system requirements.

We have lots of different docker images for Magento 2, try it out.

Sample Repo:
https://registry.hub.docker.com/u/ilampirai/docker-magento2/